# Insertion sort using fold_left with bool function passing as argument

Tags: algorithm, sorting, ocaml

I want to write simple insertion sort function using fold_left but I also want to pass function that will specify order in my sort fun.
What I don't know, is how to pass it to fold_left..

```
let rec insert f l e = 
match l with
    | [] -> [e]
    | h :: t -> if f e h then h :: insert f t e else e :: l;;

let insertion_sort f l = List.fold_left insert f [] l;;

let less x y = x < y;;

let result = insertion_sort less  [2 ; 5 ; 1 ; 9 ; 7 ; -2 ; 0 ; 124];;
```

This what I am talking about but fold_left doesn't accept that solution.
When I make specialization of sort function then it works just fine.

```
let insertLess = insert less;;

let insertion_sortLess l = List.fold_left insertLess [] l;;

let result = insertion_sortLess [2 ; 5 ; 1 ; 9 ; 7 ; -2 ; 0 ; 124];;
#   val result : int list = [124; 9; 7; 5; 2; 1; 0; -2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List.fold_left insert f ...` will apply `insert` and `f` as separate arguments to `List.fold_left`. What you want is `List.fold (insert f) ...`, which will apply `f` to `insert`, and then the result of that to `List.fold_left`.

Edit: In addition, you don't need to define `less`. You can pass `>` as a function directly by surrounding it in parentheses: `insertion_sort (<) ...`

Comment: Thx.... I bet I was tried this one but probably I have other bug and just didnt try this solution again..